# R: Error thrown while using RGDAL and RASTER packages

Tags: r, error-handling, rgdal, r-raster

To whom this may concern:

Here is the source code:

```
GRA_D1<- raster(files[[1]])
//Sets up an empty output raster: 
GRA_D1<- writeStart(GRA_D1,filename='GRA_D1.tif', format='GTiff', overwrite=TRUE)

//Write to the raster, for loop:
for(i in 1:dim(GRA_D1)[1]){

//Extract raster values at rows
d.Frame<- matrix(NA,ncol=2,nrow=dim(GRA_D1)[2])
d.Frame[,1]<- getValues(r1[[1]],i) 
d.Frame[,2]<- getValues(r1[[2]],i)

w.Frame<- as.data.frame(d.Frame)
names(w.Frame)<- c("D1_pred_disAg","D1_pred_RK")
//Apply the predictive model:
m.pred<-predict(mod.1, w.Frame) 

//Write the predictions to the empty TIFF raster
GRA_D1<-writeValues(GRA_D1,m.pred,i) 
print(i)}

//Finish writing to the raster
GRA_D1<- writeStop(GRA_D1)
```

---

I am attempting to write output to an empty TIFF raster, but I keep receiving the following error message:

```
#Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
`general_file_path\GRA_D1.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

---

I wonder if this is related to misusing functions in either the RGDAL or RASTER package.

Could someone please assist me?

Thanks in advance for your generosity.

Cheers,
AD

Answer (score 4):

Super simple fix. Cannot believe that it is this simple and that it took me this long, but here is the answer:

"rgdal" and/or "GTiff" files don't like the use of underscores in their dataset names.

When running the code with "GRAD1.tif" (instead of "GRA_D1.tif"), all works well.

Comment: You are not alone. I also spent lots of time in finding out whats the cause of error. Removing underscore made R to give more detailed error message. So it was because underscore('_') and 'Parse error at EOF, not all elements have been closed,
starting with VRTDataset'

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You really should not be doing any of this, I think, as you could do:

```
 p <- predict(r1, mod.1, filename='GRA_D1.tif')
```

(and that filename works just fine)