# R: Error output while using GRASS

Tags: r, grass

I had seen this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495487/r-error-thrown-while-using-rgdal-and-raster-packages/34924937?noredirect=1#comment57657211_34924937) but even after I remove the space or a separator in between the file name and appended number, I keep in getting the same error. Are there any suggestions for this:

```
execGRASS("r.in.gdal",flags=c("o","overwrite"),
parameters=list(input=paste(path, paste("T", as.character(i),
sep=""), sep="/"), output=paste("T", as.character(i), sep="")))

ERROR 4: `F:/Desktop/Folder/T1' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

I also checked if that particular file `T1` doesn't exist in the path. But surprisingly it does exist.

OS: Windows 10, Grass Version: 7.0

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like an error from R, but the backtick before the "F" might indicate some issue with an external (to R) package. You should: a) post more complete code, including the library calls, and b) post the results of list.files("F:/Desktop/Folder/T1")

Comment: Please tell us which package you are using (spgrass or rgrass7?) and show that the *folder* exists via `dir.exists`

Comment: @42 The script is really lengthy, so, I had to post the important part of it. But I will do it. but as you asked for the list.files(), here they are:
> list.files("F:/Srinu/RLP_Thesis")
[57] "SSP_GK3.shx"               "T 1.tif"                  
[59] "T_1.tif"                   "T1.tif"                   
[61] "UC"                        "UC.Rdata"                 
[63] "UC_Extraction_Manual.R"    "UC_Poly.dbf"              
[65] "UC_Poly.prj"               "UC_Poly.qpj"              
[73] "URC_rast.tif"

Comment: @RobertH I am currently using rgrass7. and dir.exists yielded some funny results, here they are:
> dir.exists("F:/Srinu/RLP_Thesis/T_1")


[1] FALSE


> dir.exists("F:/Srinu/RLP_Thesis")


[1] TRUE

But the list.files() says, the file exists in the lib.

Comment: I guess the problem here is, I have to input the file type i.e. "GTiff", can someone help me how to input the file type in the above code?

Comment: Rather than adding this to the comments, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `list.files("F:/Srinu/RLP_Thesis")` does not show a file called `F:/Desktop/Folder/T1`. In fact there are unrelated paths.

Either way, it should probably be something like `F:/Desktop/Folder/T1.tif`

If you are confused about how to create filenames through code, first test your function with actual filenames. You probably are looking for something like:

```
input = paste0(path, "/T", i, ".tif")
```